# Trouble with a MySQL Query

Tags: mysql

I've been running into some trouble formulating a query and was wondering if anyone can help. I simplified the table information down to the bare minimum here to try and make it easy to understand what I'm trying to do.
I have two tables A and B. A has a BId column and a Value field. B has information unrelated to the question.
What I want to do is return a set of B's based on arbitrary boolean logic on the existence of A's that contain a BId and match some value. In addition, I want to return the values that were matched. Below is an almost working example of what I want in my query:

```
SELECT * FROM B
    WHERE 
    (
         (
         EXISTS (
             SELECT a1.Value FROM A as a1 WHERE a1.BId = B.Id AND a1.Value = "X"
         ) 
         AND EXISTS (
             SELECT a2.Value FROM A as a2 WHERE a2.BId = B.Id AND a2.Value = "Y"
         )
         )
         OR EXISTS (
             SELECT a3.Value FROM A as a3 WHERE a3.BId = B.Id AND a3.Value = "Z"
         )
);
```

This is exactly what I want as far as B's returned, however I need to be able to return the values that were matched. So if there was an A that had the value X and another A that had the value Y, I would want a1 and a2 with values X and Y included in the row. If there was no A with the value Z, that would come back NULL in the row. I'm not sure of the syntax or possibility to do this.
Another approach I tried was using JOIN:

```
SELECT *, a1.Value, a2.Value FROM B 
    INNER JOIN A AS a1 ON a1.BId = B.Id
    INNER JOIN A AS a2 on a2.BId = B.Id
WHERE 
(
  (
     a1.Value = "X" AND a2.Value = "Y"
  )
  OR 
  (
     a1.Value = "Z"
  )
);
```

This properly returns the values, however it only works if X and Y are matched. If Z is matched, since there are two JOIN statements in order to accomplish the first part, I'm getting duplicated results. I'm skeptical of using this approach for this reason. It doesn't seem right to use JOIN like this.
If anyone can understand what I'm trying to do and point me in the right direction that would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably know this already, but I'll point this out anyways: As you say, your initial SQL query works, but you *I need to be able to return the values that were matched*. There is no universal answer to how to achieve this, because that's not how the query works. The `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT...)` syntax will not match any row, it will return TRUE if can find *one or more* matching rows. Meaning: Your database may or may not have *multiple* rows matching.

If I look a the database design, your table `A` seems to have a foreign key `BId` that points to a record in `B`, and you don't mention any unique keys, so most likeyly, there are multiple rows matching your conditions at least for some values.

If you try to achieve the same with JOINs, you first have to make sure you only get as many results as you have rows in `B`. (10 results in my example). Normally this is achieved by using the `GROUP BY` clause. I've also changed the syntax to LEFT JOINs, so that the grouped results will return exactly one row per record in `B`:

```
SELECT B.Id, MIN(a1.ID) AS MinA1, MIN(a2.ID) AS MinA2, MIN(a3.ID) as MinA3 FROM B
LEFT JOIN A AS a1 ON a1.BId = B.Id AND a1.value='X'
LEFT JOIN A AS a2 on a2.BId = B.Id AND a2.value='Y'
LEFT JOIN A AS a3 ON a3.BId = B.Id AND a3.value='Z'
GROUP BY B.Id
```

Now the last part is adding a condition that eliminates those results which do not match your condition, which would be:

```
HAVING (MinA1 IS NOT NULL AND MinA2 IS NOT NULL) OR (MinA3) IS NOT NULL
```

The above assumes that your table `A` has an `Id` column that you want to retrieve and that you want the lowest `Id` if more than one row matches.

Comment: Wow, that was pretty much perfect. Got it working with almost no modification, thanks!